# Image Chooser in firefox os

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-os

I am new to Firefox OS app development..

I am trying to create the simple image viewer and I write the following html code

```
  <html>
<head>
<title>Image App</title>
<link href="sty.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>


function wind()
{
var selected_file = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
alert(window.URL+"\\"+selected_file.name);

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(selected_file);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Welcome To Image APP

<input type="file" id="input" onchange="wind()">

</body>
</html>
```

But it will not load the image file. please tell the file api and functions available for firefox os

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `file`-type inputs are currently unimplemented in B2G (Firefox OS), you should be using [Web Activities](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/WebActivities) for such tasks.

If you are only interested in images, you should use the `pick` Web Activity - for details on that, see the answer in [How to use images from the device in Firefox OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168079/how-to-use-images-from-the-device-in-firefox-os).

If you want to access the storage and read possibly any other file type, you will need [Device Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebAPI/Device_Storage). Please note, that your application will need to request at least [*Privileged*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Security/Application_security#App_Types) permissions on the Firefox Marketplace.